# Converse to Wolpert's Lemma

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, teichmuller-theory, quasiconformal

Recall Wolpert's lemma:

Let X,Y be hyperbolic surfaces and $f:X\to Y$ a $K$-quasiconformal homeomorphism. For any homotopy class of curves $c$ let $\ell(c)$ denote the length of the geodesic in the class. Then $$\frac{\ell(c)}{K}\leq \ell(f(c))\leq K\ell(c)$$

I am wondering: if $f$ is a $C^1$ diffeomorphism between closed hyperbolic surfaces that has this property, is it $K$-quasiconformal? Of course it is quasiconformal for some other constant, by nature of being $C^1$.

Comment: Since you only ask about homotopy classes of curves, you should be asking instead about the homotopy (or equivalently isotopy) class of $f$, or there are trivial counterexamples.

Answer (score 6):

The answer is no, but it's actually a deep question and leads to another metric on the Teichmüller space of surfaces. The minimum quasi-conformal constant of a map in a given homotopy class is the Teichmüller metric on surfaces; it is also equal to the maximal ratio of extremal lengths of any curves. If you look at the ratio of *hyperbolic* lengths, as in your question, you get a quite different metric on the space of surfaces, studied by William Thurston: *[Minimal stretch maps between hyperbolic surfaces](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9801039)*. That paper effectively uses an asymmetric version of the inequality ($\ell(f(C)) \le K \ell(C)$), but the symmetrized version is also a very different metric from the standard one given by quasiconformal stretch. Both the asymmetric stretch metric was studied recently in detail by [Dumas, Lenzhen, Rafi, and Tao](https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.07409).

The paper *[The converse of the Schwarz Lemma is false](https://arxiv.org/abs/1411.5913)* by Maxime Fortier-Borque gives many relevant examples, although that paper is concerned with the slightly different situation of embeddings between non-compact surfaces and maps that decrease length, effectively the case $K=1$ in your questions.

Answer (score 3):

No. The issue is that quasiconformality constants are much more sensitive to local distortion than lengths. This is morally a $L^\infty$ (quasiconformal constants) to $L^1$ (lengths) comparison: $L^\infty$ bounds on a function on a finite measure space imply $L^1$ bounds, but in general the converse fails.

To sketch a counter-example, take a hyperbolic surface with an $\epsilon$-short curve for $\epsilon > 0$ very small. Such a curve has a long collar neighborhood that is close to a standard form. Leaving the core curve fixed, stretch a small annular neighborhood yielding a dilatation of $2$ at the core curve. Compensate for the stretch in a slightly larger neighborhood to produce a $C^1$ homeomorphism supported in a small annular neighborhood $V_\delta$ of the core curve. Call this map from our hyperbolic surface to itself $f_\delta$. By construction, $K(f_\delta) \geq 2$.

One sees that for any geodesic $c$, the length of $f(c)$ is  close to the length of $c$. Taking $\epsilon, \delta$ close to $0$, the numbers $\sup\limits_{c} l(f_\delta(c))/l(c)$ and $\inf\limits_c l(f_\delta(c))/l(c)$ can be made to be arbitrarily close to $1$. The key thing to do here is to bound the distortion of geodesic segments in $V_\delta$ in terms of the homotopy class  (rel $\partial V_\delta$) of the segment.

Comment: Does your contstruction work if one looks at the homotopy class of $f_\delta$, as the question probably should have asked?

Comment: @DylanThurston It won't -- this is very much a construction of a bad representative of the isotopy class. One will need to drop the $C^1$ hypothesis to work with extremizers, but after doing so this becomes an interesting question of asymptotic comparison of Teichmuller's metric and W. Thurston's asymmetric metric.

Comment: Are you sure you can't tweak it? This situation with thin curves is also the place you see that the stretch metric is very asymmetric, and I believe also should show you that the symmetrized stretch metric is different from the standard Teichmüller metric. (Also, I think the $C^1$ hypothesis is harmless, you only need to drop it if you want actual extremizers.)